# cv2.imread works with one file but not when iterating os.listdir()

Tags: python, opencv, python-3.7, imread

I try to import several images to opencv with `cv.imread()` function.
I think there is a problem with the way I give the path to `imread()`.

With one file it's ok with:

```
cv.imread('data/img.png')
```

But within a for loop:

```
imgs = os.listdir('./data')
targets = []
for img in imgs:
    target = cv.imread(img)
    targets.append(target)
```

I keep getting an array full of None values, which means opencv didn't load the file.

`print(img)` give me an output like `['btn1.png','btn2.png','btn3.png']` which seems fine to me: it's a list of string.

What I am doing wrong here and why did this string is not passed as it is printed to me?

Comment: `print(img)` will show you the problem.

Comment: yes i printed !!! but sometime me blind lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is imgs contains the filename of images but they aren't full file path, so your program cannot find the your image file.

Try to fix your program to be something like

```py
root_dir = './data'
imgs = [os.path.join(root_dir, f) for f in os.listdir(root_dir)]
targets = []
for img in imgs:
    target = cv2.imread(img)
    targets.append(target)
```

Comment: `os.path.join` exists to shield you from different ways of writing paths on different operating systems. Its generally more reliable than string concatenation (though that's getting better all the time). Do you have an example where it doesn't work?

Comment: Ok i was sending 'btn.png' instead of 'data/btn.png'. Thanks for the os.path.join() recall.

Comment: @tdelaney As my experience, I found that os.path.join() doesn't work on some Windows environment because it joins path with '/' rather than '\' as Windows path convention. However, I don't know the root cause of this problem. So, I suggested the string concatenation for the second plan when there is somebody encounter with that problem.

Comment: You can have problems if you mix ... say `os.path.join("foo/bar", "baz")`, at least that used to be a problem, but os.path.join is explicitly there to give a common way to handle posix compliant verses windows compliant path names. `os.path` is mapped to `posixpath` and `ntpath`, depending.

Comment: @tdelaney It was not in that case. I didn't mix the '/' in the path when I met the problem.

Comment: If you are going to advise against the API specifically written to fix the path problem poster has, you need more than that.

Comment: @tdelaney Ok, I removed that part.

Answer (score 0):

`os.listdir` gives the file name, not its path. You need to add the path back in or use a different API that includes the path. `glob.glob(os.path.join("path", "*.png"))` would do it. But you can also use `pathlib`

```
from pathlib import Path
targets = [cv.imread(path) for path in Path("data").glob("*.png")]
```